# How can I obtain the expected value of DNS record?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm creating a DNS propagation check tool.

For "A record" I can use a simple input box for allow user to enter expected value.

But I noted that some DNS propagation tools like viewdns.info/propagation/

are getting the expected value from somewhere.

What I tried to do was get the "NS record" and query one of these nameservers for the "A record".

Is that correct?

Comment: Have you checked `dig` ?  Are you looking for something like `dig +short NS google.com` ?.  `man dig` for more.

Comment: Hi! I'm using Net_DNS2 pear PHP extension. When you change the IP of your A record, I want to get that value from Authoritative DNS Nameservers to compare against cached A record in DNS  recursive servers.

Comment: Yes, getting all the NS records for the domain from the authoritative will allow you to compare propagation (i.e., synchronization) _within that zone_;  but that is effectively different than the tool you linked to, which compares the answers from unassociated resolvers around the world, which may/may not be stale.

Comment: `I'm creating a DNS propagation check tool.` - DNS records don't propagate so what is it that your tool is checking for? To check if a particular DNS record is cached?

Comment: Yes, you have right. Still, I didn't invented that name. But for seo it might be better to use it